# Optimizing a system of linear inequalities without using calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, linear-programming

[image]

Since $(x,y)=(6,6)$ is the point that maximizes both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, clearly this point will maximize the function $3x+2y$.

Can somebody explain to me a systematic way to find the $(x,y)$ coordinates that minimizes $3x+2y$? Since this function is strictly increasing in both $x$ and $y$, I know the solution will be a boundary point. I want to extend this reasoning to say that the point that minimizes the function must lie on one of the "corners" of the graph.

Anyway, if somebody could spread some general insight into this situation for me it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any linear objective function the set of level curves is a family of parallel lines. The maximum value must therefore occur at a vertex of the convex polygon determined by the inequalities. (The maximum might occur all along an edge, so at two vertices.)

This argument generalizes to higher dimensions.